# Satellizer: get 404 error after Facebook authentication popup AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, facebook, satellizer

I have one controller that handles my authentication for my Angular app.

```
'use strict';

/**
  * Controller used for authentications
  */

angular.module('myAPP').controller('SignInUpController', function ($scope, $location, $auth) {
    $scope.testVariable = 'Testa;dffdjklkjlakl;dklskf';

    $scope.message = 'FAILED';

    $scope.authenticate = function(provider) {
     $auth.authenticate(provider).then(function() {
       $location.path('/signinup');
       $scope.message = 'SUCCESS';
     }).catch(function(response) {
       $scope.message = response.data.message;
     });
    };

});
```

At this point in time, I am just trying to get the sign in functionality working. It appears to work. I have a button on my HTML that triggers this. It works correctly. A Facebook popup appears, and requests permission. The problem occurs on return. I get the following error.

```
angular.js:10661 POST http://localhost:9000/auth/facebook 404 (Not Found
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10661
sendReq @ angular.js:10480
serverRequest @ angular.js:10187
processQueue @ angular.js:14634
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14650
Scope.$eval @ angular.js:15878
Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15689
Scope.$apply @ angular.js:15986
tick @ angular.js:11231
```

All of my Satellizer configurations are default.

```
facebook: {
          name: 'facebook',
          url: '/auth/facebook',
          authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth',
          redirectUri: (window.location.origin || window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host) + '/',
          requiredUrlParams: ['display', 'scope'],
          scope: ['email'],
          scopeDelimiter: ',',
          display: 'popup',
          type: '2.0',
          popupOptions: { width: 580, height: 400 }
 }
```

From this code, it appears that it should be hit. But I am unsure why it doesn't work.

Does this have anything to do with ui-router? I was thinking maybe this had something to do with why it wasn't working.

I am new to Satellizer in general. 
Sorry in advance if I have over complicated a simple issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a server-side component to handle the `/auth/facebook` POST endpoint and return a valid JWT.

There are examples to implement this functionality in the [examples](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server) directory of the satellizer project.